# Using app tokens instead of user/page tokens in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Facebook's Graph API returns 3 types of tokens: User tokens, Page tokens, and App tokens. Our web app uses User and Page tokens to read and publish data to users and pages respectively. It works great except for the fact that the 60-day token lifetime requires repeated re-auths...

I then noticed [this article on App tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/), which mentions that a) they don't expire and b) they allow you to publish on behalf of users

I also tried some reading private stream data off both user and page objects with the App token, and that worked as well. So what's the deal? Can I just use the App token on all my calls instead of the User/Page generated tokens, and not ever have worry about expirations?

Answer (score 0):

The App token authenticates your app to Facebook *as the application itself*. This is fine for public data, but if you have users logging in, it's probably not what you want.

If you want to take actions on behalf of your users, you will still have to have them authenticate and use their user and page access tokens.

Comment: As I explained in my question, the app token *does* let me take actions on behalf of my users. Because of that, I don't see the point of using user/page tokens.

Comment: You should clarify your question, then. Preferably with actual code. What you are describing corresponds with the use of a User or Page access token, not an App access token. You probably still have one.

Comment: Re-read the question and the linked article. The docs make clear you can publish on behalf of the user with an app token. I've just tested it.

Comment: Don't expect this loophole to last forever, that's all I'm saying. It's obviously not what Facebook is going for. Though the whole reauthenticate every use every 60 days thing is utterly absurd and I hope FB wakes up and realizes its mistake, I'm not counting on it...